# Are there any directory permission settings in Tomcat to prevent jsp running?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

For instanace, here is the directory structure (and the Tomcat appBase is /home/user/webapps/):

```
/home/user/webapps/index.jsp
/home/user/webapps/file/
/home/user/webapps/upload/
```

Is it possible to block Tomcat from running jsps in file/- and upload/-?

For example, files have been uploaded to /file/ directory:

```
http://mysite.com/file/test.jsp (not OK, jsp won't be executed)
http://mysite.com/file/test.png (OK)
```

I have checked and tried the catalina.policy and WEB-INF/web.xml security-constraint, but in vain.

I have blocked the illegal file types in my upload servlet, but I have this question in mind as someone may upload jsp files by other means (like FTP).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the path you have provided it seems that you are putting a jsp file directly under webapps directory where a web application is expected.

Isn't your jsp file the part of the application?

If you want all the JSP files to be restricted so that they cannot be accessed from the browser directly with the url, then you can put all JSPs and whatever you want to protect in the `WEB-INF` folder. The resources placed in `WEB-INF` cannot be accessed directly.

If you want to apply `security-constraint` then also you can protect your resources based on url pattern.
You will find good information here
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html

Comment: I mean, if a file test.jsp has somehow mistakenly uploaded to /file/ directory. Then, is it possible to stop Tomcat from running this http://mysite.com/file/test.jsp?

http://mysite.com/file/test.jsp (not OK)
http://mysite.com/file/test.doc (OK)

Is it possible?

Comment: @ThomasA. Does it answer your query? I answered from my understanding. I am not sure whether this is exactly what you wanted

Comment: Sorry Prasad, I am a newbie and I thought I can hit [enter] in the comment box. I have edited my original post as well. Thank you.